# JavaScript : Login And Registration System

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to make a Login And Registration Form not using PHP & MySQL. But using JavaScript instead. Maybe using JavaScript & MySQL or maybe something else that's easier than using PHP. Anybody know a JavaScript source code for Login And Registration System? Please Help :)

Comment: you can not use JS with mysql. because js is client side. you need any server side language to perform this task

Comment: what IS a server side language?

Comment: PHP is server side language (A server side language is a language executed on the server instead of the browser), do please google these things, there are multiple comprehensive guides out there.

Comment: `php`, `ruby`... and `javascript`! Take a look [here](http://mean.io/) and [here](https://www.meteor.com/). On the other hand these frameworks are far more advanced and I recommend you sticking to `php` as it's the easiest one.

Comment: maybe he's talking about server side javascript like nodejs ?

Comment: nodejs probably best for this kinda stuff right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use javascript to send data to a mysql database directly. But, you can use AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript And XML) to send the data to a `.php` file and the php file will process the data and will give a response and AJAX will display the response in a html `<div>` element. I have written some code below as to show how you can perform an AJAX request. Here i am using the `GET` method. You can do this with or without jQuery:

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url  : "server.php",
            data : {
                // Data you want to submit to the server
            },
            success : function() {
                // code to be executed when the request was successful
            }
            error : function() {
                // code to be executed when an error occurs
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

Without jQuery:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>
<!-- Attach an onclick event to the button -->
<p id="response"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function submitData() { // define the function to be called when the button is clicked
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 
            this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "server.php", true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

I hope this answer helps your question.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript** and **MySQL** is a deadly combination.

JavaScript is a client side language and it cannot communicate with **MySQL database** without communicating with any server side language.

So here is how you can make things, send data from client (JavaScript) to server (PHP or any other Server side language) and then store/retrieve data in MySQL.

And return response to client from server using server-side language.

So, in short to do processing on MySQL database there must be a server side language to allow communication between client and database.